# Using annotation for an object sorter?

Tags: java, sorting, annotations

I am working a container to hold a list of objects (of the same class) the have certain fields that use a custom `RetentionSortable` annotation. The purpose of the annotation is two fold:

1. To mark the field as able to be compared to another objects same field.
2. And to give the sort name of the field (eg. Modification Date or First Name).

The container will then walk through the list of objects (remember they are like) and gather the list of `RententionSortable`'s that the object contains and pass the list to the GUI. The GUI will display the list and request a sortable selection and return it to the sortable which will then sort the list based on the `RetentionSortable` selected.

The purpose of this method or sorting object is to allow me to create a small container that can generically accept any object and sort it as long as it has at least one `RetentionSortable` field.

My gut screams that this is bad practice and that relying this much on reflection is a bad idea but my tests work flawlessly and better than I expected.

Is using annotation reflection to find all the fields that are annotated by a particular annotation good practice for abstract object sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are there for convenience, and your use is making the situation more convenient, so it seems reasonable.  The alternative is to maintain a separate dictionary of which fields are sortable for which objects, and is slightly more cumbersome but slightly better from a seperation of concerns point of view.

The question is really whether your object should know about the annotations or not (is the object going to be reused in another situation where the annotations do not make sense or conflict).  With a separate list of sortable fields, you can pick which to apply in any given case.

If the convenience trade-off works for you, then you should stick with the annotations, just so long as you are aware of the potential design ramifications (which may be nothing for your particular case).

Answer (score 2):

How do you think basically every annotation-driven configuration framework *works*? "Give me all the of such-and-such type fields annotated with '@Inject'" or "give me everything in package baz.plugh annotated with '@Controller'".

Whether or not it's good for "abstract sorting" or not, I don't see why not. If it works, and eliminates the need for things like bean mappers and bean info classes, what's the issue?

Comment: Huh, I never thought that my project was unique in it's annotation approach, but I didn't think entire frameworks were based off it. Good to know. That knowledge right there nulls my question.